# Internet Explorer 11 cannot recognize attr.xlink:href

Tags: css, html, svg, angular

I am very new in angular 2. I am trying to create icon component. The code below works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11.

My component looks as following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-icon',
  template: `
    <svg *ngIf="_iconClass" class="icon" [ngClass]=_iconClass 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="" attr.xlink:href="#{{ _iconClass }}" />
    </svg>
  `
})
export class MyIcon {

  private _iconClass: string = '';
  @Input() set iconClass(i: string) {
    if ((i !== undefined) && (i.indexOf('.ico') > -1)) {
      // remove .ico from iconname
      this._iconClass = i.substr(0, i.length - 4);
    } else {
      this._iconClass = i;
    }
  }
```

Then, I am using it in another component as following:

```
<my-icon iconClass="icon--user"></my-icon>
```

I haven't add all the code, hope it still makes sense. When I have checked in Developer tools, tag `<use xlink:href>` is empty. My assumption was that IE 11 can't identify `attr.xlink:href="#{{ _iconClass }}"`.

I cannot see what is wrong. I would really appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

This error is printed to the console

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference in [_iconClass in MyIcon@1:9]

```
private validateIcon(): void {
    if ((this._iconClass !== undefined) && (this._iconClass !== '') && (document.getElementById(this._iconClass) === null)) {
      if (this._validateIconRunOnce) {
        console.warn('Icon(' + this._iconClass + ') not found.');
        this._iconClass = 'not-found';
      } else {
        // delay validate icon for 3s to wait until the iconlibrary is loaded
        this._validateIconRunOnce = true;
        setTimeout(() => this.validateIcon(), 3000);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: IE never gets `attr.xlink:href="#{{ _iconClass }}"`. This is parsed by Angular and only added to the DOM after the binding was resolved.

Comment: Do yo get any messages in the browser console? Maybe sanitization modifies or removes something. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9510, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizationService-class.html

Comment: Then my assumption that I discovered the issue was wrong. I thought it should write value of `_iconClass` to `xlink:href`. For example `<use xlink:href="#brand--3d"></use>`

Comment: It should. Maybe there is an issue with id references. Rings a bell but I might be mistaken. Did you check for messages in the browser console?

Comment: EXCEPTION: TypeError: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference in [_iconClass in MyIcon@1:9]

Comment: Looks related but there is no `contains` in your code.

Comment: I am trying to get access to the DOM element and get class value. Sorry for messy code in above

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is a real mess. I could do it myself but all formatting is already lost :-/ It still doesn't contain `contains` therefore it doesn't help too much. A Plunker might help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think, it is a DOM element property. I do not have `contains` nowhere.

Comment: A Plunker might help. I don't have IE available though to debug it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunter

Thank you very much for your support. I found a solution here: https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

To support svg in IE9+ it is required to add classList.js.